# Vagrant - Not Supported the capability 'change_host_name'

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

The problem is about the capability 'change_host_name' isn't supported by the guest when I try to execute the following command line:

```
vagrant up
```

It gives me an error as the following:

```
Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'change_host_name'
on the detect guest OS 'linux', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.
```

Note that my OS is: 
OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0 and VirtualBox Version: 5.0

I've tried many solutions of others who face this issue, but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7625. It will be fixed in the next release, until then if its blocking you, you can patch vagrant yourself

If you want to patch yourself

**Method1** :

- search for the `plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb` file in your vagrant installation

  - e.g. `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb` on mac/linux default install
  - or `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb`
  - windows : `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.5\plugin‌​s\guests\ubuntu\gues‌​t.rb`
- replace with 
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlosefr/vagrant/1c631c18d1a654405f6954459a42ac19a1a2f096/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb (make sure to be with correct rights if you install as admin, you must be admin user to save the file)
- alternatively edit the file and replace all contents by

  ```
  module VagrantPlugins
    module GuestUbuntu
      class Guest < Vagrant.plugin("2", :guest)
        def detect?(machine)
          # This command detects if we are running on Ubuntu. /etc/os-release is
          # available on modern Ubuntu versions, but does not exist on 14.04 and
          # previous versions, so we fall back to lsb_release.
          #
          #   GH-7524
          #   GH-7625
          #
          machine.communicate.test <<-EOH.gsub(/^ {10}/, "")
            if test -r /etc/os-release; then
              source /etc/os-release && test xubuntu = x$ID
            elif test -x /usr/bin/lsb_release; then
              /usr/bin/lsb_release -i 2>/dev/null | grep -q Ubuntu
            else
              exit 1
            fi
          EOH
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```

**Method2** : An Alternative method to patch the file using `patch` command :

save the following file under `vagrant-guest.patch`

```
commit 00fa49191dba2bb7c6322fa8df9327ca505c0b41
Author: Seth Vargo <sethvargo@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 23 11:40:36 2016 -0400

    guests/ubuntu: Revert detection

    - Semi-reverts GH-7524
    - Fixes GH-7625

diff --git a/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb b/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb
index 9aeb7aa..f60108e 100644
--- a/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb
+++ b/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb
@@ -2,7 +2,22 @@ module VagrantPlugins
   module GuestUbuntu
     class Guest < Vagrant.plugin("2", :guest)
       def detect?(machine)
-        machine.communicate.test("test -r /etc/os-release && . /etc/os-release && test xubuntu = x$ID")
+        # This command detects if we are running on Ubuntu. /etc/os-release is
+        # available on modern Ubuntu versions, but does not exist on 14.04 and
+        # previous versions, so we fall back to lsb_release.
+        #
+        #   GH-7524
+        #   GH-7625
+        #
+        machine.communicate.test <<-EOH.gsub(/^ {10}/, "")
+          if test -r /etc/os-release; then
+            source /etc/os-release && test xubuntu = x$ID
+          elif test -x /usr/bin/lsb_release; then
+            /usr/bin/lsb_release -i 2>/dev/null | grep -q Ubuntu
+          else
+            exit 1
+          fi
+        EOH
       end
     end
   end
```

and run the following command to apply the patch

```
sudo patch -p1 --directory /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/ < vagrant-guest.patch
```

Just replace `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5` (or `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb`) with your vagrant folder installation

Comment: Nice one - fixed it for me to, big kudos due

Comment: On a default windows install, C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.5\plugins\guests\ubuntu\guest.rb  Took me a while to find that file...

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for Windows host and linux guest?

Comment: @user1177476 I think so, some users reported it was working from windows - the file path should be  C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.5\plugin‌​s\guests\ubuntu\gues‌​t.rb; if you don't find it there, make a global search on your disk - edit the file and replace the content with what I added in the message, it should work

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 keeps the file at /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/ubuntu/guest.rb

Comment: As of the latest vagrant (1.9.1), the same sort of error occurs.  The patch here no longer applies though.

Comment: @mc0e strange, not able to replicate on 1.9.1, weird though as it seems the fix has been applied in code

Comment: I was trying to run a 3rd party vagrant box recipe that references the box bento/centos-6.7.  The box hasn't been updated in a while, and the vagrant provisioning doesn't include a `yum update` .  Doing that update allowed me to move forward to the next bit-rot issue with the box.

Comment: You are a lifesaver :)